# Linking images in WordPress Paginated Post

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages, linking

I have a paginated post on WordPress with about 5 pages. I want to set it up so that the images in the content from the previous page automatically link to the following page.

I've used the following code in `functions.php` file:

```
<?php 
  add_action('the_content',function($content) {
    global $page, $numpages, $multipage;
    if ( $multipage ) {
      $nextPage = $page + 1;
      if ( $nextPage <= $numpages ) {
        $link = _wp_link_page( $nextPage );
        $content = preg_replace('/(<img(.+?)\/>)/i','<a href="'.$link.'">$1</a>', $content);
      }
    }
    // send back our content, modified or not
    return $content;
  });
?>
```

The code above ALMOST works. When I substitute the `$link` variable for an actual URL e.g. `http://google.com`, all the images in a paginated post end up linking to `google.com`. However, when I place the variable `$link` there, none of the images link anywhere. Not sure if there's an issue with me using the `_wp_link_page` variable.

I'm totally lost as to why it won't work when the `$link` variable is placed, but it works with any other value.

Hopefully someone can assist. Let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use `add_filter()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_wp_link_page()` returns a HTML string and not just the URL address of the link. So, if the link's URL address is `http://example.com/blah/2/`, then `_wp_link_page()` would return:

```
<a href="http://example.com/blah/2/">
```

..i.e. it returns the opening `a` tag for that link.

So replace the following:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img(.+?)\/>)/i','<a href="'.$link.'">$1</a>', $content);
```

..with this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img(.+?)\/>)/i', $link . '$1</a>', $content);
```

Comment: PS: Tried and tested with WordPress version 4.9.4.

Comment: Thanks @Sally. Your solution worked. Just have to modify the syntax a little to the following. `$content = preg_replace('/(<img(.+?)\/>)/i',' '.$link.'$1</a>', $content);`

Comment: You're welcome! And I'd appreciate if you could [accept](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) or [vote up](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) my answer. =)